# WPF graph column graph

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am trying to set up a column graph with the time. Why is my graph not showing up on the main window?
I initialized the graph object like this :

```
private Chart graph = new Chart();
```

my chart functions are:

```
private void DrawTimeChart(string testName,double time)
    {
        Series sinSeries = new Series();
        sinSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        sinSeries.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        sinSeries.BorderWidth = 2;

        sinSeries.Points.AddXY(testName,time);
        }

    private void cnvChart_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

        graph.Width = 250;
        graph.Height = 250;
        host.Child = graph;
        // Add the chart to the canvas so it can be displayed.

        this.cnvChart.Children.Add(host);
    }

    private void SetUpChart(Chart funcChart, int marginX, int marginY)
    {
        graph.Series.Clear();
        graph.ChartAreas.Clear();
        graph.ChartAreas.Add("Default" + new Random());
        // Add a series with some data points.

        funcChart.Width = 349;
        funcChart.Height = 177;

        funcChart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(marginX, marginY);

        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "X";
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1.0;

        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.0}";
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;

        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Y";
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1.0;
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = 0;
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.0}";
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;

        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 6;
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = -6;
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 7;
        funcChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -7;
    }
```

I'm calling the functions like this:

```
     SetUpChart(graph,5,5);
     DrawTimeChart("test1",time1);
```

in regards to XAML, that's how my canvas is written:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="cnvChart"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="177"
         Margin="0,242,392.333,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="349"
         Loaded="cnvChart_Loaded" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
```

Comment: why are you using WindowsFormsHost?

Comment: I don't think there is host for WPF Charts. It is also a project specification to use the host from windows forms